# Prolog - print list 2

Tags: list, printing, prolog, sliding-tile-puzzle

I have a Prolog project to create about the "Puzzle 8". I'm new with this language. I have many doubts so I came here to resolve at least one. Here is my code:

```
puzzle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0]).

affiche_puzzle :-
    puzzle(Puzzle),
    printe(Puzzle).

printe([]).
printe([H1,H2,H3|Puzzle]) :-
    format('~w ~w ~w~n', [H1, H2, H3]),
    printe(Puzzle).
```

My doubt is why when I use the printe([H1,H2,H3|Puzzle]) the result is this and not the numbers of the list:

```
_G4716 _G4719 _G4722
Puzzle = [] ;

_G4843 _G4846 _G4849
Puzzle = [_G4843, _G4846, _G4849]...
```

I would be grateful if you help me!

Comment: Your code should work as is without changes if you type in (query) `affiche_puzzle`. What did you type in as a query?

Answer (score 2):

you must call each predicates with suitable arguments:

> ?- affiche_puzzle.
>  1 2 3
>  4 5 6
>  7 8 0
>  true.
>  
>   ?- printe([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]).
>  a b c
>  d e f
>  g h i
>   true.